Identify & test an obscure IC?
I want to check whether the (only) IC in my mum's old Viking Husqvarna 190 Selectronic sewing machine is damaged (from a short). The chip itself is a 24-pin DIP (0.6 in "wide") marked with:
≈/B234
41-17-415-01

I can find no service manual nor replacement parts (not even for the entire control board as a unit) which is unsurprising for a consumer machine from the 80s.
Any tips for how to go about such -- or is just a lost cause?

What caused the short?  A 24 pin DIP is probably a microprocessor, given the age of the machine.  You won't be able to easily test it because what it doesn depends on how it is programmed.  What is wrong with the machine?

It would help to have pictures, but it's unlikely the chip will be easy to test, as JRE says.

Thank you both, you're probably right. That's why I didn't bother to post pictures of the whole board and the machine. I'll tinker some more with it.

The chip /B234 with marking 41-17-415-01 is made by National Semiconductor.
Most likely, it custom chip and we will not find the datasheet. I think that pins 24 are VCC and pin 12 is GND. Please , check this version.

Adam7 - Hi, Where did the image come from? To comply with the site rule on referencing, details of the original source of copied / adapted material must be provided by you, next to each copied / adapted item. If the original source is online & public, please [edit] the answer & add the webpage/PDF/etc. name & its link (URL) (e.g. website name + webpage title + its URL). If the source is offline (e.g. printed book / private intranet) then [edit] the answer & add full source details e.g. title, author, page, publisher, edition. TY (More rules in [tour] & [help].)

I understand why the post was redacted, but the image (found in the edit history) is precisely equal to my board.

I was afraid of, yet expecting, the chip being a custom one with no accessible data sheet. Thank you.

@KlaymenDK - Hi, Re: "I understand why the post was redacted" FYI, "redacted" has a specific meaning on Stack Exchange (it's something that mods can do to remove a version from the visible edit history) and that was not done here. What happened was that instead of adding the required reference for the copied image, the author chose to edit the post & remove that image. I realise that might be what you mean by "redact", but to avoid confusion from readers who know the SE meaning of "redact", I wanted to make it clear that mods did not redact anything here.
